# How to achieve RPO of 15 minutes

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We are migrating a transaction-related database on SQL Azure with the following specs.

> Single Database, vCore, General Purpose, Provisioned, Standard-series
> (Gen 5), Locally Redundant, 1 - 12 vCore Database(s) x 1 Month, RA-GRS
> Backup Storage Redundancy, 200 GB Point-In-Time Restore, 2 x 800 GB
> Long Term Retention

The said database currently is on SQL Server on-prem, where log shipping to a DR site, helps us to commit to an RPO of 15 minutes to business.

Locally Redundant SQL Azure with vCore at this price point commits a max RPO of 12 hours (I might be wrong here).

Can we do something like log shipping or log backups every 15 minutes to achieve the same on the current priced SKU?

Comment: can't you just create a script which will extract a backup and upload to a storage account, then just schedule it to run every X minutes?

Comment: A full backup will consume too much compute and basically slow down the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL Database takes

"Transaction log backups approximately every 10 minutes."

[Automated backups in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/automated-backups-overview?view=azuresql)

And with "RA-GRS Backup Storage Redundancy" those backups are replicated to a second region.  So that should meet your 15min RPO without additional work.

If you need a tighter RPO or RTO you can configure [Active geo-replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/active-geo-replication-overview?view=azuresql), which will create a readable secondary you can use for disaster recovery.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks a lot for that. That helps. A couple of questions, where can I see the 10 min Transaction logs backup or restore to that backup manually?

Comment: You restore in the Azure Portal, or with a script.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/recovery-using-backups?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal

Answer (score 0):

You can sync or replicate the data changes on that database every 15 minutes to a local on-premises database or to another Azure SQL using a free tool named [SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-data-sql-server-sql-database?view=azuresql). The replication can be bi-directional or in one direction. The frequency at which the sync occurs could be in seconds, minutes, hours and days.